# Interfaces. Why am I getting a type error when trying to use an external function?

Tags: interface, typeerror, ethereum, solidity

Here is the code for my main smart contract.
Errors on the last two functions.

> from solidity: TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call.
> Invalid implicit conversion from type(uint256) to uint256 requested.
> --> contracts/DIV4.sol:39:57:    | 39 |         randomness_interface(_random).fulfillRandomness(uint256);    |
> ^^^^^^
>
> from solidity: TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call.
> Invalid implicit conversion from type(bytes32) to bytes32 requested.
> --> contracts/DIV4.sol:43:55:    | 43 |         randomness_interface(_random).getRandomNumber(bytes32);    |
> ^^^^^^^

```
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol";
import {randomness_interface} from "./randomness_interface.sol";

contract Divergence is ERC1155, Ownable  {
    uint256 public constant One = 0;
    uint256 public constant Two = 1;
    uint256 public constant Three = 2;
    uint256 public constant Four = 3;
    
    constructor() ERC1155 ("https://ipfs.io/ipfs/dsfgijdsfklj348rue0ur099045948.json"){
        _mint(msg.sender, item1, 1000, "" );
        _mint(msg.sender, item2, 130, "" );
        _mint(msg.sender, item3, 65, "" );
        _mint(msg.sender, item4, 3, "" );
    }

    function uri(uint256 _tokenId) override public view returns (string memory) {
        return string(
            abi.encodePacked(
                "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/Qmf4WrTGA2fYJXitigvqJ7FDVMPreJQW4of8HZ1k5Wzkd3?filename=Divergence1",
                Strings.toString(_tokenId),
                ".json"
            )
        );
    }

    function generateRandomNumber(address _random) external(bytes32 requestId) {
        randomness_interface(_random).fulfillRandomness(uint256);
    }

    function getRandomNumberfromOutside(address _random) external {
        randomness_interface(_random).getRandomNumber(bytes32);
    }
```

`Interface.sol` file.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface randomness_interface {
    function fulfillRandomness(uint256 randomness) external view returns (uint);
    function getRandomNumber(bytes32 requestId) external;
}
```

Finally, the file with all the randomization happening.

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.6;


import "https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/develop/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBase.sol";


contract RandomNumber is VRFConsumerBase {

    bytes32 public keyHash;
    uint256 public fee;
    uint256 public randomResult;

    constructor() VRFConsumerBase(0xdD3782915140c8f3b190B5D67eAc6dc5760C46E9, 0xa36085F69e2889c224210F603D836748e7dC0088) public {
        keyHash = 0x6c3699283bda56ad74f6b855546325b68d482e983852a7a82979cc4807b641f4;
        fee = 0.1 * 10 ** 18; //0.1 LINK
    }

    function getRandomNumber() public returns (bytes32 requestId) {
        return requestRandomness(keyHash, fee);
    }

    function fulfillRandomness(bytes32 requestId, uint256 randomness) internal override {
        randomResult = randomness.mod(100).add(1);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing correct arguments to the functions.

-

```
 function generateRandomNumber(address _random) external(bytes32 requestId) {
        randomness_interface(_random).fulfillRandomness(uint256);
    }
```

You are calling `randomness_interface(_random).fulfillRandomness` and `fulfillRandomness` expects

```
  function fulfillRandomness(bytes32 requestId, uint256 randomness)
```

I am not sure if this is the correct way of calling `fulfillRandomness`

```
function generateRandomNumber(address _random) external(bytes32 requestId) {
        randomness_interface(_random).fulfillRandomness(uint256);
    }
```

Because as far as I know, `fulfillRandomness` gets called by the chainlink node, so you make request, get the random number and then chainlink will call `fulfillRandomness`. I think you should have written like this:

```
function fulfillRandomness(bytes32 requestId,uint256 randomNumber) internal override{

}
```